# Start many Virtual Machines at once on CloudStack

Tags: bash, apache-cloudstack

Any idea to start many Virtual Machines at once?

Currently i am using Cloud Monkey CLI with a startvm.sh script to start VMs.
However they start in serial, once after another.

Anyway to start probably 10VM at one time, in parallel?

```
#! /bin/bash
result=$(cloudmonkey start virtualmachine id="e10bdf21-2d5c-4277-9d8d-791b82b9e3be")
result=$(cloudmonkey start virtualmachine id="XXX1")
result=$(cloudmonkey start virtualmachine id="XXX2")
result=$(cloudmonkey start virtualmachine id="XXX3")
result=$(cloudmonkey start virtualmachine id="XXX4")
echo $result > Done.txt
```

Comment: run each command "in the background", by appending the `&` at the end of each line? Why bother storing `result=` if you're going to overwrite it on the next call to `cloudmonkey`? The usefulness of starting 10 VMs in parallel is a separate issue. Good luck.

Comment: Glad it worked. Consider posting the difference in startup times, and any interesting stuff from looking at `top` output. Good luck.